# (Weighted)AdjacencyMatrix for custom properties

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is it possible to make (`Weighted`)`AdjacencyMatrix` from a graph whose elements have custom properties?

Consider this graph:

```
g = Graph[{
      Property[DirectedEdge[0, 1], {"WaterFlow" -> x, "PipeWidth" -> 10.0}],
      Property[DirectedEdge[1, 2], {"WaterFlow" -> x + y, "PipeWidth" -> 8.5}],
      Property[DirectedEdge[2, 1], {"WaterFlow" -> y, "PipeWidth" -> 8.5}],
      Property[DirectedEdge[2, 3], {"WaterFlow" -> x, "PipeWidth" -> 10.0}]
    }]
```

[image]

How do I make one `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` weighted by `"WaterFlow"` and another one weighted by `"PipeWidth"`?

For example, the one for `"WaterFlow"` would be:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify custom properties to set edge weights using undocumented option `EdgeWeight`:

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g, EdgeWeight -> "WaterFlow"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: "WaterFlow" edge weight]

```
WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g, EdgeWeight -> "PipeWidth"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: "PipeWidth" edge weight]

Since this option is not documented, its behavior could be changed later though.